# Facebook Crawler Issues and Questions

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, web-crawler

This post consists of 3 points:

1. Question: How long does Facebook crawler scrapes new information from your website by default? That is meaning you don't force it to fetch new scrape information using the debugger.
2. Issue: I am having a problem in which the share dialog is showing "Page not found" but after scraping new information for that page, it showed the proper page information.
3. Issue: I have a page (http://kabayanabroad.antdomus.volenday.com/kabayan-manifesto) in which I assigned an og:image to show in share dialog. When I use the facebook debugger it is showing the correct image. However, once I share it to facebook it is showing a different image consistently. Please see images below:

**FROM FACEBOOK DEBUGGER:**
[image: FROM FACEBOOK DEBUGGER]

**FROM FACEBOOK TIMELINE AFTER SHARING:**
[image: FROM FACEBOOK TIMELINE]

*the red facebook logo is also part of the website but with only 128x128 size

Comment: FB debug tool shows errors for http://kabayanabroad.antdomus.volenday.com/ right now. All meta elements pertaining to the og:image are commented out in your source code currently.

Comment: @CBroe yes but the link with an error is http://kabayanabroad.antdomus.volenday.com/kabayan-manifesto. I edited the question to include the link.

Comment: That looks fine for me, in share dialog preview as well as in the final post on Facebook. So likely just a caching issue.

Comment: I confirm the caching issue. It's OK now.
Any answer for the 2 points?

RE: #2 - will the shared post with "Page not found" be updated automatically to show the correct post title or I will have to share it again?

Comment: As for your question 1), https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/opengraph/using-objects#update // An already existing post will not automatically be updated, but you as the post owner can request FB to update the content. You need to go into the single post view (so from your feed/timeline, click the date link on top of the post), there is an option called “Refresh share attachment”.

Comment: Thanks for wanting to mark this question as resolved. However, we don't use the title for this on Stack Overflow - the best way is to add a self-answer, and to click the tick mark to the left of it. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks halfer. @CBroe as per halfer's comment, please compile your comments into an answer so that I can mark it as the solution to this issue. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The URL you had a problem with looked fine for me, in share dialog preview as well as in the final post on Facebook. So likely just a caching issue.

As for your first question, how often the scraper visits your site – see https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/opengraph/using-objects#update

Already existing posts will not automatically be updated, but you as the post owner can request FB to update the content. You need to go into the single post view (so from your feed/timeline, click the date link on top of the post), there is an option called “Refresh share attachment”.